# Return response from API and perform some other actions at the API level

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, api, jax-rs

I am using jax-rs jersey for Rest API. I need API endpoint which needs to send response and perform some extra action after returning response which is updating the global variable. How can I achieve it?

I tried using Executor to execute a time taking task, expecting the API would return the Response and then execute this task, but the client using my API seems to be in hanged state.
Moreover, I found AsyncResponse using @Suspended annotation, but my intention is not to send the response again after the initial response. The updated stuff will only be used when the client requests again.

```
global_var = 0;
execute.execute(() -> {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                            try {
                                logger.error("In executor service "+i);
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                global_var +=i; 
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                logger.error("Exception while sleep " + ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
return Response.ok(global_var).build();
```

Expecting API will return global_var as 0 initially, later when again the request comes from client, it will send the updated global_var value.
But the API is in hanged state even on the first request

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `execute.execute(()`

use `executor.submit()`

Depending on implementation, `execute` can be done on calling thread instead of background one.